# Python non-linear slicing

Tags: python, slice

Given a list `a`, I can slice it by doing:

```
a[start:end:step]
```

However this is only linear slicing.
For instance, I would like to select the indexes that are powers of 2.
Unfortunately this does not work:

```
a[slice(2**x for x in range(len(a))]
```

Is there a way to avoid loops when non-linear slicing is required?

**EDIT**:
mainly I need this to modify the list. E.g.

```
a[*non-linear-slicing*] = [*list-with-new-values*]
```

Comment: No, there is no non-linear slice mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EDIT**:
>   mainly I need this to modify the list. E.g.
>
> ```
> a[*non-linear-slicing*] = [*list-with-new-values*]
> ```

Great. Then we can use that list of new values to drive this thing. Demo:

```
>>> a = range(17)
>>> newvals = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']

>>> for i, val in enumerate(newvals):
        a[2**i] = val

>>> a
[0, 'foo', 'bar', 3, 'baz', 5, 6, 7, 'qux', 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Or if you also have the indexes in a list already, then use `zip` instead of `enumerate`:

```
>>> a = range(17)
>>> indexes = [1, 2, 4, 8]
>>> newvals = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
>>> for i, val in zip(indexes, newvals):
        a[i] = val

>>> a
[0, 'foo', 'bar', 3, 'baz', 5, 6, 7, 'qux', 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

And since you just mentioned coming from R, maybe you want to use NumPy, which does support such indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(13)
>>> a[[1, 2, 4, 8]] = [111, 222, 444, 888]
>>> a
array([  0, 111, 222,   3, 444,   5,   6,   7, 888,   9,  10,  11,  12])
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I did in the end. I just thought it would be cool if in the future it is possible to do non-linear slicing (R can do it already, for instance)

Comment: @Pigna I added two more solutions, I suspect the NumPy one might be the best for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension:

```
is_power_of_two = lambda num: num != 0 and ((num & (num - 1)) == 0)
print [item for i, item in enumerate(a) if is_power_of_two(i)]
```

Comment: This is still a `for loop`.

Comment: @Laszlowaty It's a loop in the background... Slicing also requires some form of loop to implement, I guess.

Comment: True, but loop in `.slice` is not visible to the user. And you must admit that this list comprehension is not very user friendly :)

Comment: @Laszlowaty I agree slicing is nicer. If I knew of another syntax for slice that applies, I'd answer with it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I updated the question though: I don't need to print, but to assign to the sliced part of the list

Comment: @Pigna I can think of another list comprehension to do that, but it'd be terrible and it really misses the point.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can try this:

```
    # Example list
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

result = list(map(lambda y: l[y], list(filter(lambda x: (x>0 and (x & (x-1) == 0)),list(range(0,len(l)))))))
print(result)
```

The result is:

```
[2, 3, 5]
```

But if I were you, I wouldn't use that because it is barely readable.

Comment: The indexes should be powers of 2, not the values

Comment: It needs another fix. The output isn't correct. It should return elements at position `2^0 = 1, 2^1 = 2, 2^2 = 4, 2^3 = 8` . Like `[2, 3, 5, 9, ..]`

Answer (score 1):

Why iterate over the whole list, when you just need the `2 ** i`th elements. Which improves complexity dramatically.

```
a = range(100)

def two_power_slice(lst):
    result = []
    for i in xrange(len(lst)):
        j = 2 ** i
        if j > len(lst) - 1:
            break
        result.append(lst[j])      
    return result

print two_power_slice(a)
```

I think you can also use logarithm to avoid using `if` altogether.

**Edit:** Improved version, Fixed errors.

```
def two_power_slice(lst):
    if not lst: return lst
    result = []
    for i in xrange(int(math.ceil(math.log(len(lst), 2)))):
        result.append(lst[2 ** i])      
    return result
```

Comment: The first one crashes when the length is a power of two. The second one crashes when the list is empty. And once it says `a` instead of `lst`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks for the insight, corrected the second one.

Comment: The first one is easy to fix as well :-). Oh and btw your text says `i ** 2` instead of `2 ** i`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a[1],a[2],a[4],a[8] = [11,12,14,18]
# a = [0,11,12,3,14,5,6,7,18,9]
```

I know no way to build the `a[1],a[2],a[4],a[8]` in a generic way as comprehensions or generator will not work as they do not admit the assigment operation.